# Turn image array images to buttons AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, imagebutton

I'm creating an app with a search function. I display the images by loading from the array the one's which match the search criteria. All the images are loaded from the library. I want to be able to click on an image as though it were a button. Once I click I want to goto frame 3 and change a variable integer to say which image was clicked on so that I can display the information about the photo in frame 3. Can I do this using an event listener say

```
imagesArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imageClick);
function imageClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
    current = i;
}
```

or similar,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it won't be as easy. First, Bitmaps do not process events, so you can't assign a listener directly to a Bitmap object. Next, there is no "i" available in such a construction, you have to determine that "i" by yourself. To do that, you parse `event.target` property, which is the object that's been clicked. You wrap each `Bitmap` object into a separate `Sprite` object, assign listeners to these sprites, then you parse `event.target` to get the relevant object reference out of it, grab the index via `indexOf()` call, and assign it to global `current` variable.

```
for (i=0;i<imageArray.length;i++) {
    var sp:Sprite=new Sprite();
    sp.addChild(imageArray[i]);
    // position "sp" correctly here
    addChild(sp);
    sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imageClick);
}
function imageClick(e:Event):void {
    var content=e.target.getChildAt(0); // the object that was wrapped
    var i:int=imageArray.indexOf(content);
    if (i==-1) return; // OW, out of array
    current=i;
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that setting "current" to "i" would work as the function wouldn't be running at the same time as the for loop.

I'm assuming that because you're using the [i] that you've added the event listeners in a for loop?

What you could do is:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < (howeverManyTimesToRun); i++)
{
    imagesArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imageClick);
    imagesArray[i].myIndex = i;
}
```

And then in your function (outside of the for loop)

```
function imageClick (e:MouseEvent) {
    gotoAndStop(3);
    current = e.currentTarget.myIndex;
}
```

Also in your for loop you might want to add

```
imagesArray[i].buttonMode = true;
```

To change the mouse cursor to a hand when their mouse goes over your image.

Comment: I should mention that i wrote this also assuming that your images were MovieClips... I probably shouldn't have.